# How do I set my Swift 2.0 path?

Tags: swift, swift2

When using the terminal I did have the current version of Swift running where it would show the below. I ran the command `xcrun swift` to get to this point.

```
Welcome to Swift!  Type :help for assistance.
  1>
```

However, I accidentally ran the below command twice...

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
```

And now my terminal is showing the below...

```
Welcome to Swift version 1.2. Type :help for assistance.
  1>
```

Do anyone know how I get back to my original installation of Swift? I tried reinstalling Xcode but still doesn't seem to have fixed my issue.

Comment: you can do ```xcode-select -switch <path>``` again

Comment: And point it at your Xcode-beta install.

Comment: I tried this but still didn't change anything. I ended up reinstalling Xcode and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is: don't use the command line at all. Just choose from the pop-up menu at the bottom of Xcode's Locations pref pane.

[image]

Your Xcode beta containing Swift 2.0 will be in that pop-up menu. Choose it.

Comment: Yes. That's what I said. The problem _is_ that they were already set like my picture. What I said to do was: set them so they pointed at the Xcode beta _instead_. Your reinstallation of Xcode was a total waste of time. You simply had to read what I said to do, and do it.